Finding analytic maximum of complex polynomial with positive semidefinite constraint containing the same polynomial
I am trying to find the closed-form expression for (or be reasonably confident that one cannot exist) the maximum of $\lvert f_{max}\rvert$ such that $\mathbf{D} \succeq 0$, where:
$$f_1(z) = k_1 z + k_2$$
$$f_{max}(z) = f_2^2(z) = k_3z^2 + k_4z + k_5$$
are two functions of a single complex variable $z$ with known complex coefficients $k_n$, with matrices:
$$\mathbf{M} = \begin{pmatrix} f_1 & f_2 \\ f_2 & z \end{pmatrix}$$
$$\mathbf{D} = \mathbf{I} - \overline{\mathbf{M}}\mathbf{M}$$
It is simple enough for me to create an optimizer for this problem, but as I hope to consider many different combinations of $k_n$, it would be worthwhile to instead evaluate closed-form expressions.
By the maximum modulus principle, $\lvert f_{max} \rvert$ attains a maximum along the domain boundary if $\mathbf{D} \succeq 0$ is a bounded nonempty connected open subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Is this true, and if so, what is an expression for the boundary? My intuition tells me that this is when at least one eigenvalue is zero. I have tried solving for the real/imaginary (and magnitude/phase) components of $z$ for both $\lambda_1 = 0$ and $\lambda_2 = 0$ but have been unable to come up with a closed-form solution for either case. If I would have been able to, my plan was to plug the result back into $\lvert f_{max} \rvert$ and use the second derivative test to determine the other component of $z$ at the maximum point. But since I was unable to come up with closed-form solutions, I feel like I might have either a fundamental misunderstanding of the problem posed here, or an unsolvable problem (perhaps due to $f_2 = \pm\sqrt{f_{max}}$).
